# ffmpeg : How can I send a H.265 encoded stream to wowza?

Tags: ffmpeg, wowza, h.265

I managed to encode H.265 to an output file like this :

```
ffmpeg -i test.m2ts -c:v libx265 -c:a copy output.mp4
```

and I managed to stream a H.264 file to wowza like this :

```
ffmpeg -re -i sample.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -vprofile default -vprofile baseline -r 24 -g 48 -vb 150000 -strict experimental -acodec aac -ab 96000 -ar 48000 -ac 2 -f rtsp -muxdelay 0.1 rtsp://username:password@127.0.0.1:1935/ApplicationName/myStream
```

But I just cant seem to stream a H.265 to a rtsp stream.

If I use the libx265 in the command above I get the error :

```
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the console message with -loglevel verbose

```
>ffmpeg -re -i sample.mp4 -vcodec libx265 -vprofile default -vprofile baseline -r 24 -g 48 -vb 150000 -strict experimental -acodec aac -ab 96000 -ar 48000 -ac 2 -f rtsp -muxdelay 0.1 rtsp://username:password@127.0.0.1:1935/ApplicationName/myStream -l
oglevel verbose
ffmpeg version N-69156-gff5b9a1c Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jan 20 2015 00:38:00 with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-
libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --
enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54. 17.100 / 54. 17.100
  libavcodec     56. 20.100 / 56. 20.100
  libavformat    56. 19.100 / 56. 19.100
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Routing option strict to both codec and muxer layer
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'sample.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
    encoder         : Lavf52.73.0
  Duration: 00:09:56.46, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 524 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 424x240 (432x240), 420 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24 tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      handler_name    : DataHandler
      encoder         : libx264
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 99 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      handler_name    : DataHandler
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 00000000050f6e60] w:424 h:240 pixfmt:yuv420p tb:1/24 fr:24/1 sar:0/1 sws_param:flags=2
[graph 1 input from stream 0:1 @ 0000000002c38700] tb:1/48000 samplefmt:fltp samplerate:48000 chlayout:0x3
[libx265 @ 0000000002c172a0] [Eval @ 000000000022aca0] Undefined constant or missing '(' in 'baseline'
[libx265 @ 0000000002c172a0] Unable to parse option value "baseline"
[libx265 @ 0000000002c172a0] Error setting option profile to value baseline.
Output #0, rtsp, to 'rtsp://username:password@127.0.0.1:1935/ApplicationName/myStream':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: qt
    encoder         : Lavf52.73.0
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: hevc, none, q=2-31, 128 kb/s, 24 fps (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      handler_name    : DataHandler
      encoder         : Lavc56.20.100 libx265
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac, 0 channels, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      handler_name    : DataHandler
      encoder         : Lavc56.20.100 aac
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> hevc (libx265))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

Comment: does "-loglevel verbose" give any more hints? Please post full console output here as well

Comment: @rogerdpack I  have  included the -loglevel verbose message now, thank you.

Comment: Yes, thank you. It "streams" now, but the test Video does not show on the test players. Thats another issue. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appears libx265 has no "profile baseline" option based on the slightly hidden output line

`Error setting option profile to value baseline.`